# The animation timeline won't show up right in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

It doesn't show the: "create frame animation" option when I select the timeline window. :/
What do I do?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could the issue be that you do not have Photoshop CS6 Extended? Or does it normally work?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure. I read a thread an hour ago stating that it does indeed work with Photoshop CS6 Standard, maybe this is an error caused by Photoshop that that option is not there? - Zoey

Answer (score 2):

In your screenshot, the animation is **already a frame animation** as noted by the first frame in the Timeline Panel.

[image]

The `Timeline Panel` is titled "Timeline" regardless on the actual animation type - Timeline or Frame. However, the *contents* of the panel look markedly different based upon the animation type.

Comment: But unfortunately, I am not able to animate without that option. This is an error caused by Photoshop, and I just want to know if that's true, and how I would contact photoshop.

Comment: Once again, You **already have a frame animation**. It's **already** created. Photoshop can't create a frame animation from a frame animation. There is **no** error in Photoshop. It's functioning exactly how it is supposed to.

Comment: @FaithfulArts Scott is right. You should do a little more research on how to use a frame by frame animation in photoshop. What you have there is a **single** frame. You can't animate just one frame. You need to create another frame (the new frame button to the left of the delete button in Scott's image) with your character in a different position and only then you will see the play button enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same problem as I had. Try this solution I just found. In Photoshop CS6 click on;

*Window > Extensions > Mini Bridge* - it shows Timeline - then click on Create Frame Animation.

For Animation, you don't need PSD Extended but for the 3D features, you do (from what I understand from all the reading I've just done about this). I have CS6 & it works. (I refuse to move to CC).

Cheers - hope it helps someone. ✌️